# C# Unit Testing with Rhino Mocks unable to find assembly Rhino.Mocks

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

When I execute my unit test cases with NUnit + Rhino Mocks, I get the following error.

```
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.
  ----> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Unable to find assembly 'Rhino.Mocks, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0b3305902db7183f'.
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DefaultInstance()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection..ctor(DbContext context, String nameOrConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at SHS.SMI.CustomerSettingsService.DatabaseContext..ctor()

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.AppDomain.get_Evidence()
   at System.AppDomain.get_EvidenceNoDemand()
   at System.AppDomain.get_Evidence()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()
```

I have included the following in my AssemblyInfo.cs (Assembly file under test)

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Rhino.Mocks")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

Note: If I add Rhino.Mocks to the Global Assembly Cache, it works fine!

Any help is really appreciated!

Let me know if you need any other information

Comment: Check this answer and see if it makes any sense to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8484156/5233410

Comment: Can you check your assembly's app.config and see if there are any binding redirect values in there for RhinoMocks.  Also, if you have a common output folder for all of your test assemblies, make sure they are all using the same version of RhinoMock and that the version in that output folder is the version you are referencing.